# How to insert new cell into UITableView in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I'm working on a project where I have two `UITableView`s and two `UITextField`s, when the user presses the button the data in the first `textField` should go into the `tableView` and the second go into the second `tableView`. My problem is that I don't know how to put data in the `tableView` each time the user pushes the button, I know how to insert data with `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` but that works for one time as far as I know. So what method can I use to update the `tableView` each time the user hits the button?

Comment: What have you tried?  You say "tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:" only works "as far as" you know.  Why not try it in your button's method?

Comment: @Max von Hippel 
what I did was :
the tableView takes the data from an array
so when I append an  item to the array I use this method : tableView.reloadData
this way when ever I append an item the array will go to the "CellForRowAtIndexPath" and pull the informations again from the array :)

Answer (score 183, accepted):

Use `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` to insert a new cell when the button clicked.

> As @vadian said in comment, `begin/endUpdates` has no effect for a single insert/delete/move operation

First of all, append data in your tableview array

```
Yourarray.append([labeltext])
```

Then update your table and insert a new row

```
// Update Table Data
tblname.beginUpdates()
tblname.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([
NSIndexPath(forRow: Yourarray.count-1, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
tblname.endUpdates()
```

This inserts cell and doesn't need to reload the whole table but if you get any problem with this, you can also use `tableview.reloadData()`

---

**Swift 3.0**

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: yourArray.count-1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

---

**Objective-C**

```
[self.tblname beginUpdates];
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:Yourarray.count-1 inSection:0]];
[self.tblname insertRowsAtIndexPaths:arr withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
[self.tblname endUpdates];
```

Comment: Nice that you have provided the Objective-C version as well. It helps sometimes!!

Comment: @RashmiRanjanmallick ...yes same thing I thought and edit my answer...so people understand translations :)

Comment: `begin/endUpdates` has no effect for a single insert/delete/move operation.

Comment: No, you can omit `begin/endUpdates` for a single insert operation and it is working anyway.

Comment: @vadian hmm ... thats what I think ... but what do you mean by `begin/endUpdates has no effect for a single insert/delete/move operation` this sentence ??? sorry for too many questions ..

Comment: *No effect* means there is no difference if the lines are there or not. You need the lines only for e.g. an `insert` line followed by a `delete` line or multiple calls of the same line in a repeat loop.

Comment: Does the the call to `beginUpdates`/`endUpdates` have to be on the main thread? or it will handle that itself automatically?

Comment: Looks like `begin/endUpdates` would cause the `tableView` to calculate the size of every cell. The scrolling get smoother after I remove them.

Comment: this works fine for a tableView with one section , but with multiple dynamic sections it crashes if the item is being placed into a new section and also for the first item added to the tableview.  So for multiple sections check your dataSource to see if it's the first item in the section.  if so use insertSection instead of insertRow, otherwise use the above.

Comment: doesn't inserting at `row: yourArray.count-1` insert the new row at the second-to-last row?

Comment: @mattb not really .. array count starts from 1 like we have 10 rows and index starts from 0. So to insert the 11th row, right now we have index till 9. So we have to set -1 means at 10th index we need to insert 11th row. hope u understand now :)

Answer (score 33):

***Swift 5.0, 4.0, 3.0*** Updated Solution

**Insert at Bottom**

```
self.yourArray.append(msg)

self.tblView.beginUpdates()
self.tblView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath.init(row: self.yourArray.count-1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
self.tblView.endUpdates()
```

**Insert at Top of TableView**

```
self.yourArray.insert(msg, at: 0)
self.tblView.beginUpdates()
self.tblView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath.init(row: 0, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
self.tblView.endUpdates()
```

Comment: How's this achieved with a collection view? I can insert multiple items with ease.... but this is inserting at index 0. When the item is selected the previous index 0 is shown.

Answer (score 22):

Here is your code for add data into both tableView:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var table1Text: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var table2Text: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var table1: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var table2: UITableView!

    var table1Data = ["a"]
    var table2Data = ["1"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    @IBAction func addData(sender: AnyObject) {

        //add your data into tables array from textField
        table1Data.append(table1Text.text)
        table2Data.append(table2Text.text)

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            //reload your tableView
            self.table1.reloadData()
            self.table2.reloadData()
        })


        table1Text.resignFirstResponder()
        table2Text.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    //delegate methods
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if tableView == table1 {
            return table1Data.count
        }else if tableView == table2 {
            return table2Data.count
        }
        return Int()
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if tableView == table1 {
            let cell = table1.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

            let row = indexPath.row
            cell.textLabel?.text = table1Data[row]

            return cell
        }else if tableView == table2 {

            let cell = table2.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

            let row = indexPath.row
            cell.textLabel?.text = table2Data[row]

            return cell
        }

        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}
```

And your result will be:

[image]

Comment: How was the storyboard laid out for this?

Comment: The reason I am asking is that I am trying to do something similar and I am getting a message in the console which tells me the tableview is being forced to a resize

Comment: This helped a lot. Thank you.

Comment: Reference to your answer, Can I ask question related to add section and move row?

Answer (score 3):

**For Swift 5**

**Remove Cell**

```
    let indexPath = [NSIndexPath(row: yourArray-1, section: 0)]
    yourArray.remove(at: buttonTag)
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()

    self.tableView.deleteRows(at: indexPath as [IndexPath] , with: .fade)
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
    self.tableView.reloadData()// Not mendatory, But In my case its requires
```

**Add new cell**

```
    yourArray.append(4)

    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.insertRows(at: [
        (NSIndexPath(row: yourArray.count-1, section: 0) as IndexPath)], with: .automatic)
    tableView.endUpdates()
```

Comment: Why do you create an NSIndexPath then cast it into IndexPath? Just create an IndexPath initially. I usually do it even simpler: `[0, 1]`. Zero is the section, 1 is the row.

Comment: Yes, you can use IndexPath instead of NSIndexPath.

Answer (score 1):

You can find this comment in Apple's UITableView framework:

```
// Use -performBatchUpdates:completion: instead of these methods, which will be deprecated in a future release.
```

So, you should use this:

```
tableView.performBatchUpdates { [unowned self] in
    tableView.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: animation)
}
```