# how to add comments text in UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextview

i am new to social media App , i just want to know how to Add comments in textview and when user press done button the entered text should update it in UITableViewCell and if user again tries to comments that comment also to be added in Cell and i want to reuse the data as well can u suggest any sample code for this or any tutorial?

Comment: check this...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31870206/how-to-insert-new-cell-into-uitableview-in-swift/31870301#31870301

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic layout.

Here is the project I use dynamic layout: https://github.com/khuong291/Yelp. Just download and have a look at it.

And whenever user want to comment more, you have to create a new label or textview and put that string in it.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you need to add your data in any collection type (Ideally Array) & Then you just need to reload the table to display added data.