# Inserting a new cell in between the cells in tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode6

i here attached a snapshot of my sample output.now it has two cells that is according to arraycount which i used at number of rows in section method.i have calutalted the break time ,now i want to insert one more cells in between that two cells to dispay the break time . here is my code whic i did ....please help me to do this .thanks in advance

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"TableViewCell";


 TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[TableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];


}

NSLog(@"%@",self.arrData1);

NSDictionary *tempDictionary= [self.arrData1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

//NSLog(@"%@",tempDictionary);

NSString *strFunctionCodeValue =[tempDictionary objectForKey:@"function_code"];
NSString *strStartTimeValue = [tempDictionary objectForKey:@"start_time"];
NSString *strEndTimeValue = [tempDictionary objectForKey:@"end_time"];
NSString *strTotalUnitsValue =[tempDictionary objectForKey:@"total_units"];
NSString *strTotalTimeValue = [tempDictionary objectForKey:@"total_time"];
//NSString *strBreakTimeValue = [tempDictionary objectForKey:@"break_time"];



cell.lblFunctionCodeValue.text = strFunctionCodeValue;
cell.lblStartTimeValue.text = strStartTimeValue;
cell.lblEndTimeValue.text = strEndTimeValue;
cell.lblTotalUnitsValue.text =strTotalUnitsValue;
cell.lblTotalTimeValue.text = strTotalTimeValue;
//cell.lblBreakTimeValue.text = strBreakTimeValue;



return cell;
```

}

Comment: check this out....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31870206/how-to-insert-new-cell-into-uitableview-in-swift/31870301#31870301

Comment: Insert the dictionary (a custom class is highly recommended) into the data source array and reload the table view.

Comment: please give some examples ....

Comment: Hi anyone please help me to do this ,i want to use insertrowatindexpaths methods ,please give some examples