# Add custom cell to UITableView programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, custom-cell

this is different than what i've found on this website because everything i've found adds multiple cells upon a button push.  I don't have a button and i don't see the functionality of adding multiple pieces of information to a single cell.

I made a custom cell for my UITableView and I believe it is working fine.

I have a subclass of UITableView and I only need one cell to be added. Each cell has 5 text fields that I need to add information to.

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("onlyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! tableCardTableViewCell

    cell.field1.text = info1

    cell.field2.text = info2

    cell.field3.text = info3

    cell.field4.text = info4

    cell.field5.text = info5

    return cell
}
```

above is how I tried to add the information.

Below is how is how I tried to add the cell to the tableview

```
    myTable.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31870206/how-to-insert-new-cell-into-uitableview-in-swift/31870301#31870301

Comment: Have you create the cell in the storyboard? Also if you only have 1 cell then you just need to set the variable to 1 in the numberOrRowsInSection method.

Comment: i have a .xib file with the cell.  I don't have it in the storyboard because i'm trying to create it using only the code

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **2D Arrays in swift**
So that you can access the 5 elements of information regarding to each row by using indexPath.row every time

Then you can assign by using **For Loop** with index path.row as first parameter and index of for loop as second parameter respectively to the 2Dimensional array

I hope it works
I am very new to Swift, so i am not able to explain with complete code in swift

*Some code*

```
var array2D = Array<Array<String>>()


[array2D .count] //returns the number of arrays present inside *array2D*
```

thank you