# Add value in NSArray in Tableview in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview

This is my code ,I am trying to add value in Array and populate them into Tableview .

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [self.greekLetter count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSString *SimpleIdentifier = @"SimpleIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SimpleIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:SimpleIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = self.greekLetter[indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

when i add the value herd code value it is showing correct in table view.

```
self.greekLetter=@[@"prem",@"nath",@"kumar",@"shree"];
```

I want to add value dynamically to the array and it will show in table view. Can some one pls help me.

Comment: Add the value and call `reloadData` on the table view.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31870301/4601170

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your `greekLetter` is `NSMutableArray`:

```
-(void) addDataToGreekLetter {
    [self.greekLetter addObject:@"TestObject"];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Assuming that your `greekLetter` is `NSArray`:

```
-(void) addDataToGreekLetter {
    NSMutableArray *temp = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: self.greekLetter];
    [temp addObject:@"TestObject"];
    self.greekLetter = [NSArray arrayWithArray:temp];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of reloading the entire `UITableView` you could try just using `insertRowsAtIndexPaths`. It doesn't reload all the cells and gives you a nice animation on top of it.

For example:

```
-(void)addData:(NSString *)text{

    //provided your self.greekLetter is NSMutableArray 

    [self.greekLetter addObject:text]

    NSIndexPath *index = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(self.greekLetter.count - 1) inSection:0];

    [self.tableview insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[index] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
}
```