# How to insert a row or cell to tableview in "swift 3.0"? and I got the answer

Tags: ios, uitableview, insert, swift3

The code below is for deleting and inserting cells in tableview.
Deleting is working. But what is the code for inserting??

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == .delete {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        list.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    else if editingStyle == .insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
      tableView.beginUpdates()
      tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: yourArray.count-1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
      tableView.endUpdates()
    }    
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31870206/how-to-insert-new-cell-into-uitableview-in-swift/31870301#31870301

Comment: But it is not working in swift 3.0 @EICaptainv2.0

Comment: @KayCee please add here what you have tried while coding.It will help us understand and solve problem

Comment: `yourarray.append([labeltext])`  - What is labeltext here? @sanman

Comment: `tblname.beginUpdates()
    tblname.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([
        NSIndexPath(forRow: Yourarray.count-1, inSection: 0)
        ], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
    tblname.endUpdates()`   - beginupdates and endupdates is not there in swift 3. inserting syntax is also different I think. @sanman

Comment: @KayCee yourarray.append([labeltext]) means append objects your datasource array.And then find out indexpaths for added objects and insertrows for the same.

Comment: "labeltext" stands for ? @sanman

Comment: @KayCee "labeltext" means your new object(s) to be added to your array,for which you want to insertrows.