# Is there a way to delete user specified lines from text view?

Tags: ios, swift

Attempting to write a delete function. I am building an app to list courses after a button is clicked. I am using a text view to display this information and appending each course with a new line. Now i want the user to be able to delete a course. I was thinking if i can keep track of which line the user is on right now, then i can also tell which line the user will like to delete. Thoughts? Maybe there is a better way of doing this, perhaps using labels instead of text view?

EDIT: Use table view /s

Comment: Whats wrong with a table view ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `UITableView` to create a `section` for "Courses" and create `rows` in it with your courses.

And you should handle the insert/delete with the [UITableView methods.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31870206/how-to-insert-new-cell-into-uitableview-in-swift)

[Check this out,](https://www.ralfebert.de/tutorials/ios-swift-uitableviewcontroller/) or similiar tutorials out there.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use a `UITableView` to achieve this. One benefit to using a `UITableView` is you can use built in functionality for deleting and creating new items. [Here is a guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/CreateATableView.html) on `UITableView`.

Comment: I did not know of a table view! Thank you all for your replies!

Comment: @BestGiraffeNigeria You should read the tutorials, it will make everything simpler and really the way you should do i.t