# swift: tableView crashes when trying to add a new row

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm following this tutorial because I want customized cells:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kYmZ-4l0Yy4

But it doesn't say how to add new cells so I just did this according to what I found here:
[How to insert new cell into UITableView in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31870206/how-to-insert-new-cell-into-uitableview-in-swift)

```
elements.append(["new data"])
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: elements.count-1, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

I switched elements array from let to var because it gave me an error

And then the moment it gets to `tableview.beginUpdates()` or `tableview.reloadData()` it crashes giving me this error:

> "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
>   Optional value"

This is the rest of the code:

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellActiveCastingSites") as!TableViewCell_CastingSite

    cell.cellView.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    cell.lblCastingName.text = elements[indexPath.row].0
    cell.lblCastingWebsite.text = elements[indexPath.row].1

    cell.CastingLogo.image = UIImage(named: "CastingLogo_" + elements[indexPath.row].0)

    cell.CastingLogo.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    cell.CastingLogo.layer.masksToBounds = true

    cell.CastingLogo.layer.borderWidth = 1
    cell.CastingLogo.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Can you show your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: I added it now.. I'm new to stack overflow sorry about the incorrect formatting lol

Comment: Your line `tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: elements.count-1, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)` seems to be written in Swift 2. You need to update that line.

Comment: Have you connected your `tableView` outlet to your storyboard?

Comment: Hey @rmaddy it crashes way before it even gets to the line....

Comment: @Paulw11  I have this, is this what you mean? `@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!`

Comment: @QuocNguyen Hi I added it to the question... do you have any idea maybe?

Comment: You need to connect that outlet to the scene in the storyboard

Comment: @CastingMonkeys: element of `elements` array has 0 and 1 (array with 2 element), but when you add data, you only add ["newdata"] (only 1 element). So it crash. I think so

Comment: @QuocNguyen no I tried that already, I just wanted to simplify that's why I wrote it like that, but actually even if I don't add ANY new data, just reload, it crashes :(

Comment: @Paulw11 What do you mean? in the Referencing Outlets it's connected - is there something else that I am missing?

Comment: Set a breakpoint and check; something is `nil` and the tableview outlet seems the most likely.

Comment: @Paulw11 I set a breakpoint, it goes to this line `@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!` then comes back to the line `tableView.reloadData()` and then the moment I click f7 again, it crashes. It won't allow me to step into the reloadData() function so I don't know what's going on

Comment: That is because your `tableView` outlet is `nil`. When you hit the breakpoint type "po tableView" in the debugger console; it will show nil. You need to fix the connection in your storyboard.

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes you're right - it is returning nil!! do I have to delete the current connection and do it again?

Comment: @Paulw11 so after deleting everything and starting from scratch - turns out the error was actually just the fact that I was calling the function of inserting a new element through another ViewController....

Comment: @QuocNguyen so after deleting everything and starting from scratch - turns out the error was actually just the fact that I was calling the function of inserting a new element through another ViewController....