# Swift Newbie Argument labels '(_:, IndexPath:)' do not match any available overloads

Tags: swift, xcode

When I call the tableView function I get the error in the title. My question is why won't the function take the two arguments even though they are of the requested type? Again I'm a newbie so please forgive me if the answer is obvious.

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController { 
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { 
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "itemCell") as! UITableViewCell 
        let name = Array(shopItems.keys) [indexPath.row]
        let cost = Array(shopItems.values) [indexPath.row] 
        cell.textLabel?.text = name + String(cost)
        return cell 
    }
}
```

When I call the function like this:

> "TableViewController.tableView(shopTableView, IndexPath: NSIndexPath)" I get the error: "Argument labels '(_:, IndexPath:)' do not match any available overloads"

Comment: Why are you calling this method in the first place? You shouldn't call this method. You should write this method, and let the framework call it.

Comment: I want it to be called when the user presses a button, so that a cell is added every time the user taps it

Comment: That's not how you add new cells to a table view. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31870206/how-to-insert-new-cell-into-uitableview-in-swift).

Comment: If I run my app with adjusted code provided in that post I get this error: "attempt to insert row 0 into section 1, but there are only 1 sections after the update"

Answer (score 0):

Try use

```
 let name = shopItems.keys[indexPath.row]
```

Instead of

```
    let name = Array(shopItems.keys) [indexPath.row]
```

Better don't use force wrap, when it's not nesesery.
Try change

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "itemCell") as! UITableViewCell
```

to

```
 guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "itemCell") as? UITableViewCell else { 
    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

EDIT: As @Sh_Khan say replace

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
```

to

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
```

Comment: When I change the name and cost constants I get this error: "Cannot subscript a value of type 'Dictionary<String, Int>.Keys' with an index of type 'Int'". And I also still get my original error

Comment: I didn't know it was a dictionary. In that case, restore the version you had

Comment: Yeah, sorry I should've mentioned that. Basically I have a dictionary that takes a string and an Integer and this function is supposed to create a table View cell with the String and Integer as its label

Comment: *Better don't use force wrap*. No, in this case force unwrapping is welcome because the code **must not** crash if everything is hooked up correctly. If it does it reveals a **design** mistake. Optional Binding displays nothing in case of the mentioned design mistake and you have no idea why. The bad user experience is the same in both ways.

Comment: @vadian - to better user experience You can show pop up with information about error and dismiss view. It's better than crash

Comment: Runtime checks for errors which can be resolved at compile/design time is unnecessarily expensive. There are only a few rare cases where force unwrapping is perfectly fine. This is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy and quick way to figure out yourself the proper *overload*

1. Select the entire method and press <kbd>⌘/</kbd> to comment out the code.
2. On the top level of the class type `cellForRow`. The first item in the code completion list is the proper method.
3. Press <kbd>Return</kbd> to insert the correct method.
4. Comment in the *wrong* method by selecting it again and pressing <kbd>⌘/</kbd>.
5. Copy and paste the body of the wrong method into the correct one.
6. Delete the rest of the wrong method.

Comment: Thank you, I still cannot get it work though. Sweeper mentioned that I shouldn't call the method but I don't get why. Don't I have to provide the function with a Table View on which to perform the method?

Comment: Sweeper is right. You must not call the method yourself. The method is called by the framework right after you called `tableView.reloadData()`. But you have to override also `numberOfRowsInSection` to return the number of rows you want to display.